# How to get dynamically a changing value from onchange function on javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have an `<input type="text" id="changeText" onchange="changeFct()">` and I need to get the text outside of the onchange function.

This is my javascript :

```
function changeFct(){
  var getText = document.getElementById("changeText").value;
  return getText;
}

var getTextFromOutside = changeFct();
console.log("from outside >>>> ", getTextFromOutside);
```

So I need to get the modifications dynamically from outside of the onchange function.

***Edit***
The idea is to write into css files using a web interface (this interface contains inputs in order to have some colors, font size etc)

**I'm using JSzip to unzip a folder that contains all css files** this part works.

Imagine my html input is used to ask a font-size. so I'll need to get the value usinge a listener for example.

The problem is that I'll need to use this value into a promise, I'm using promises because I'll need to modify 3 css files one by one.

Comment: Totally wrong, var getTextFromOutside = changeFct(); this statement run before on-change that is the reason for undefined

Comment: Thank you @GovindSamrow I agree and wanted to know if there is a way to make it work (do i really need promise ?)

Comment: You need to add more detail what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @GovindSamrow, first I want an onchange (or something else) on a text input tag, in my js script, the function onchange needs to return a value, i want to be able to get the value from the outside of the onchange function, and to have a new value on every change on the input

Comment: then use Global variable for this.

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work because `changeFct` will only be called once the value of the input text has `changed`. This is why you have undefined in the output.

Instead of adding `onchange` event in the element, instead of use the function `addEventListener` :

```
function changeFct(value){
  Promise.resolve(value).then(function(val){
    console.log(value);
  });
}  

 document.getElementById('changeText').addEventListener('change', function(){
    changeFct(this.value);
 }, false);
```

Here you can do whatever you want with this value, instead of declaring a global variable that will pollute the `window` object.

Comment: Hi @Dimitri , I'm testing your script, is there any way to use first a global variable, to modify it inside the addEventListener, and then get it (modified) from the outside ?

Comment: Why do you want to get the value from the outside?

Comment: I need it outside to use it into a promise

Comment: I mean, I have an input, in every change or modification of this input, I'll need to have this modification outside of the function

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in what you want to achieve with the promise ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Global varible but use this after onchange:

```
   var getText = ''; //Declare variable outside 
    function changeFct(){
      getText = document.getElementById("changeText").value;
    }
```

But again you need a statemnet that execute after onchange function;

```
otherFunc(){
 console.log("from outside >>>> ", getText );
}
```